# Visual Basics 2015 Script to open multiple URL in one browser

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am currently creating a windows application form. In this i have placed button and i am looking to have the button open my default web browser with multiple tabs of websites i have included in the script.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a48271b-26dd-448d-9130-737efaf17cd6/open-multiple-url-using-visual-basic-2008?forum=vbgeneral
this thread has pretty much what i am looking for but the code opens multiple windows and all I am after is one window multiple tabs instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So your script works basically, but it opens multiple browser sessions instead of tabs?

Comment: @GrindelOh yes that correct

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you are looking for:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Dim Urls() As String = {"www.stackoverflow.com", "www.google.com"}
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    Sub Main()

        Do Until counter = 2

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Urls(counter))

            counter = counter + 1

            Thread.Sleep(2000)

        Loop

    End Sub

End Module
```

I tested it myself with IE11 but it should work with any browser you've defined as default.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Use URLs.UpperBound for loop, or `FOR EACH s as string in URLs`

Comment: @rheitzman feel free to edit my code. I just quickly set something up to try it out myself and see if it opens browser sessions or tabs.

Comment: Code's fine - just wanted Anne to be aware of other ways to iterate string arrays.

Comment: thanks guys giving it a go now and will let you know

Comment: unfortunately it still opens multiple windows instead of tabs

Comment: @AnneD The only thing that I a can think of, is that your default browser reacts different to this type of command than IE does. I don't have any further suggestions sorry.